# How to use javascript to preform various functions on a website

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to log in to an account, visit a particular URL, click on something at that URL, and then log in to the next account for a list of about 100 accounts. I'm not quite sure where to start here. Any guidance on where I can look to teach myself how to do things like this?

Comment: these kind of activities are generally done with Puppeteer these days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a broad request... You tagged the post as Javascript so I am going to assume you want the solution in that language.

What you are probably looking for is something called browser automation library. One such is called Selenium https://www.selenium.dev/

It has support for multiple languages such as Python, Java, JavaScript and more!

It allows you to launch a browser window and control it using code. Have a look around the internet, there will be many examples out there.